# What is the difference between calling .first and .first()?

Tags: templating

So here's something I've never been able to figure out about Twig. Does it make a difference if you include the parenthesis for functions or not?

In other words, what is the difference – if any – between calling

```
craft.entries.first
```

and

```
craft.entries.first()
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it was Ben Croker who mentioned this [nugget from the Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables) in his Craft course on development:

> For convenience's sake `foo.bar` does the following things on the PHP layer:
>
> - check if `foo` is an array and `bar` a valid **element**;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `bar` is a valid **property**;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `bar` is a valid **method** (even if `bar` is the constructor - use `__construct()` instead);
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `getBar` is a valid **method**;
> - if not, and if `foo` is an object, check that `isBar` is a valid **method**;
> - if not, return a **null value**.
>
> `foo['bar']` on the other hand only works with PHP arrays:
>
> - check if `foo` is an array and bar a valid element;
> - if not, return a null value.

The more you find out about Twig, the more you don't know!

Answer (score 11):

On a more philosophical note; Put yourself in the shoes of `first()`. It's a **method**, doing an important job in the Craft eco-system. It prides itself on returning the most important and relevant data in an efficient and unencumbered way. Serving up entry after entry, asset after asset, 24 hours a day, all week, all year. Never complaining, never getting any praise.

And you want to treat it like a simple **property**? As a dumb, brainless reference to some data that some other method created? How do you think that makes `first()` feel? How would **you** feel if someone treated **you** as property?

I know you're a good person with a big heart, Mats. I'm sure you will do the right thing and treat `first()` with the respect it deserves, even though it means that you'll have to write a few more characters a day.

Comment: If I could give this answer multiple upvotes, I would. FWIW, I do make sure that first() never leaves home without its parentheses. Poor little fella just looks so naked and defenseless without them.

Comment: I've never considered having empathy for a method before.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no difference. Twig will recognize a method without parenthesis as simply being a method without parameters.

The only "gotcha" is if you *also* happen to have a property by the same name in your class. It's probably a bad idea to do so anyway, but if you have a method & property sharing the same name, Twig will parse the parenthesis-less name as the property value instead.